# Как использовать JSON5 в C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Консольное приложение на С#

Со стороннего сайта получаю json в формате json5:

```
[{
    contentId: 'f1654c004d0207fab3f1f30d9d5f7b1a',
    date: new Date('05/14/2018 10:50:00')
},
{
    contentId: 'f1954d004d0287fab3f2f30d9d5f7b1a',
    date: new Date('08/24/2018 10:50:00')
},
...
]
```

Хранится в строковой переменной.

**Вопрос в том какие варианты работы есть с таким существом в C#**??

Что пробовал:

1. Подключить библиотеку [JSON5 .NET](https://github.com/json5/json5-dotnet). Не работает, не компилируется, написано что билд сломан
2. Пройти регуляркой, остановился на проблеме полей с new Date: [вот тут](https://regex101.com/r/rH5qG8/4)

Comment: 3. Поискать не отдает ли сайт обычный JSON или хоть еще что-то. 4. Пройтись конечным автоматом для замены кавычек, удаления new Date. Но это может накрыться при очередной модификации.

Comment: 5. Поискать еще библиотеки, например для C++, после чего адаптировать к .net.

Comment: @AK, во-первых спасибо за желание помочь.
json такой используется на одном госсайте, для формирования контента. AJAX запрос возвращает такой json, и еще один скрипт его преобразует в html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам может помочь Json.Net от Newtonsoft с кастомным конвертером даты.

Вообще, если гуглить does json.net support json5 мы сразу [выходим](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1316) на то, что поддержка ("большей части" - май 2017 года) уже есть. Но действительно, такие даты как у вас не поддерживаются.

Странный у вас вообще формат времени. [Официальная спецификация json5](https://spec.json5.org/) вообще ничего не говорит о формате времени, это оставлено на откуп спецификациям на Javascript:

> JSON itself does not specify how dates should be represented, but
>   JavaScript does.
>
> There is no right format; The JSON specification does not specify a
>   format for exchanging dates which is why there are so many different
>   ways to do it.
>
> The best format is arguably a date represented in ISO 8601 format (

(См. тут: [The “right” JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952652/5752652))

Но... у вас не [ISO 8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) даты... у вас вообще в вопросе одни строки, а по ссылке с регуляркой другие (и подозреваю, что там правильно: формат `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS`).

В принципе, должно помочь написание кастомного конвертера, чего-то типа JavaScriptDateTimeConverter - вот например, очень [похожий пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31577833/5752652).

Я не знаю, все ли даты приходят в таком формате, не знаю, насколько этот гос. сайт специфицирует такой формат (или может неожиданно перейти на ИСО 8601 - 2001 и поломать вам код), но в принципе, можно написать свой конвертер, обложить для надёжности юнит-тестами и тогда уже использовать в продакшене.

Вот вам рабочий приме для основы:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = @"[
    {
        contentId: 'f1654c004d0207fab3f1f30d9d5f7b1a',
        date: new Date('05/14/2018 10:50:00')
    },
    {
        contentId: 'f1954d004d0287fab3f2f30d9d5f7b1a',
        date: new Date('05/14/2018 17:43:05')
    }]";
    var parsed = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass[]>(source);
    parsed.Dump();
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string contentId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JavaScriptGovSiteDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

public class JavaScriptGovSiteDateTimeConverter : JavaScriptDateTimeConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);

        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token == null || token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            if (!isNullable)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Null value for type {0} at path {1}", objectType.Name, reader.Path));
            return null;
        }
        if (token.Type != JTokenType.Constructor)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid Date constructor \"{0}\" at path {1}", token.ToString(), reader.Path));
        }
        var constructor = (JConstructor)token;
        if (!string.Equals(constructor.Name, "Date", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid Date constructor \"{0}\" at path {1}", token.ToString(), reader.Path));
        }

        var values = constructor.Values().ToArray();

        if (values.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid Date constructor \"{0}\" at path {1}", token.ToString(), reader.Path));
        }
        else if (values.Length == 1)
        {
            DateTime dt;
            if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(values[0].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy H:m:s", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
                throw new Exception("date format is not MM/dd/yyyy H:m:s");

            return dt;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Вот сейчас прям совсем неожиданно было");    
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помогу немного с датой, это формат [JavaScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2.1). Что касается C#, то тут уже строка даты должна быть переписана (в нечто, вроде этого: `{"point_in_time": "\/Date(1310669017000)\/"}`). Нашел на [данном](https://markembling.info/2011/07/json-date-time) ресурсе описание про это все. Ну а вообще, JSON5 еще очень рано как по мне использовать... Его толком то еще не изобрели и инструментов по поддержке всего этого нету еще нормальных.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за пояснения насчёт формат даты, я на фронтенд редко заглядываю. А насчёт преобразования строки - нужно просто аккуратно разобрать JToken. Поправил на скорую руку пример, на который кидал ссылку - на приведённом формате даты работает.

Comment: @AK, Огромное спасибо, за столь подробное объяснение.
С форматом дат, действительно ошибся, не правильно вставились, в регулярке было верно.
В продакшене буду два варианта парсинга использовать по этому json и по html странице (теоретически данные должны совпадать), так что если один накроется, другой должен продолжать работать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, согласен про раннее использование json5. Я не сразу понял, что вообще мне приходит за формат. Вроде json, а кавычек на ключах нет, на значениях одинарные, еще и new Date смутила.