# Сравнение даты, полученной из json

Tags: c#, datetime

Сервер [отдаёт дату](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=users&ususers=Example&usprop=registration&utf8&format=json) вот в таком формате: `2015-04-24T07:00:51Z`. Мне нужно узнать, не старше ли эта дата, например, трёх дней. Код ниже, естественно, не работает. Вероятно, дело в CultureInfo, но как мне тогда привести всё к общему знаменателю (формат выдачи сервером)? Или проблема в ином?

```
if ( (DateTime.UtcNow - stuff["query"]["users"][0]["registration"]).TotalDays < 3 )
```

Заране благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, сервер отдает дату в string формате (если вытянуть ее из json). А Вы хотите ее сравнить с DateTime форматом. Попробуйте использовать методы DateTime.TryParce() (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) или  DateTime.TryParceExact() (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) а уже после сравнивать

Comment: @foxhound вы правы в части того, что нужно преобразовать строку в дату. но вот делать то лучше описав формат json и передав его парсерам json, чем выковыривать разные кусочки через try parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте Json.Net для работы, он вам сам сконвертирует в дату.

```
var source = "{\"batchcomplete\":\"\",\"query\":{\"users\":[{\"userid\":24920566,\"name\":\"Example\",\"regist" +
    "ration\":\"2015-04-24T07:00:51Z\"}]}}";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Abc>(source);
data.Dump();
data.Query.Users[0].Registration.Dump();
```

Вспомогательные классы создал [сервисом](https://app.quicktype.io/#r=json2csharp):

```
public partial class Abc
{
    [JsonProperty("batchcomplete")]
    public string Batchcomplete { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("query")]
    public Query Query { get; set; }
}

public partial class Query
{
    [JsonProperty("users")]
    public User[] Users { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
{
    [JsonProperty("userid")]
    public long Userid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("registration")]
    public DateTimeOffset Registration { get; set; }
}
```

Вывод linqpad:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Библиотека [Json.Net умеет распознавать даты разных форматов](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm), также можно написать собственные парсеры, [например вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/830323/213987) или [посмотрите на en so](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjson.net%5D+custom+date+format).

Comment: Смотрел кстати тоже на результат этого сайта, не как не могу понять, почему именно DateTimeOffset использует, ведь обычный DateTime вполне будет рабочим вариантом?