# Десериализовать объект из Json без дополнительных вложенных классов

Tags: c#, json

Имеется следующий json:

```
"Events":[  
  {  
     "_id":{  
        "$oid":"5b918a9757904a1a5421dfd2"
     },
     "Messages":[  
        {  
           "LanguageCode":"en",
           "Message":"msg"
        }
     ],
     "Prop":"https:xxx.com/...",
     "Date":{  
        "$date":{  
           "$numberLong":"1536264837000"
        }
    },
    "ImageUrl":"https://yyy.com",
    "Priority":false,
    "MobileOnly":false
  },
```

Под него я сделал класс:

```
public class Event
{
    public string _id;
    public List<Message> Messages;
    public string Prop;
    public DateTime Date;
    public string ImageUrl;
    public bool Priority;
    public bool MobileOnly;

}
```

Но так как свойства `_id` и `Date` являются объектами со своими вложенными объектами то я не могу напрямую их записать в поле.

Как мне это обойти чтобы не создавать модели специально под эти поля? Возможно это можно сделать через конструктор либо через дополнительные приватные поля но у меня не получилось. Когда пытался сделать `[JsonConstructor]` то Десериализер игнорировал этот конструктор.

Comment: Нужно уточнять библиотеку Json. Для, например, newtonsoft есть JsonConverter аттрибут

Comment: @vitidev Извините. Да использую newtonsoft. Указываю атрибут. Но вот дальше как быть непонимаю. Какого типа должно быть поле которое будет повторно парситься чтобы добраться до конечного значения? И какой функцией снова проверсти парсинг?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить объект такого вида на c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: @tym32167 Не совсем. Там товарищ создал классы для каждого вложенного в root класс поля. А я хочу создать так скажем поле которое отличается типом от всех вложенных классов и сразу присваивать ему значение из последнего дочернего элемента.
То есть чтобы `"$numberLong":"1536264837000"` парсилось из родительских `"$date"` и `"Date"` конвертировалось из UtcTime в DateTime и присваивалось полю класса. Все это чтобы не создавать лишние классы и для легкости дальнейшего обращения к полю.
Представьте вам нужно было бы обращаться так: `datetime(event.date.childrendate.numberlong, datetime.utc)`.

Comment: уточняю. Это API и API не мое поэтому я незнаю почему так было сделано. Это делается для удобного обращения к полям. Выше я привел пример.

Comment: так сгенерируйте POCO объекты для десериализации и их уже мапьте на ваши модели как хотите

Comment: @tym32167 я и говорю что генерация создаст то что вы и привели в примере. А это совершенно лишнее действие и классы. Почему я не могу на конструкторе описать какие либо действия с принимаемым объектом и даже не хранить его в в том виде в каком он есть а взять оттуда одно единственное значение например? Я не хочу создавать
`class Event{ class Date{ class DateChild { DateTime numberlong }}` и потом еще внутри конвертировать.

Comment: Вам в сторону кастомного конвертера и самостоятельного разбора дерева. Что-то в духе такого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/830323/213987 или такого: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/5752652 Если не лень -- можете поразбираться в устройстве JToken'ов.

Comment: @AK Спасибо, это ближе всего. Завтра попробую. Надеюсь поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы не хотите делать POCO-объекты для десериализации и потом мапить их как душе угодно — то вам нужно смотреть в сторону кастомных ковертеров, а для этого понимать как устроено дерево разбора.

Приведу очень упрощённый пример для первого вашего поля - для Id, даты оставлю на самостоятельное изучение.

Объявляете кастомный конвертер:

```
public class Event
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomIdConverter))]
    public string Id;

    public DateTime Date;

    public string ImageUrl;
}
```

В нём пишете всю логику обработки:

```
public class MyCustomIdConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);

        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token == null || token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            if (!isNullable)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Null value for type {0} at path {1}", objectType.Name, reader.Path));
            return null;
        }

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            // На скорую руку, тут по-хорошему нужны разные проверки
            if(token.First().HasValues)
                return token.First().First().ToString();
        }

        throw new Exception("Вот это вот сейчас неожиданно было");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Первый раз писать такие вещи конечно тяжело (мапить привычнее, проще и быстрее — а мы вас с tym32167 отговаривали), я обычно пишу сначала заготовку до строки var token - а потом смотрю в отладчике какие у меня типы токенов и ориентируясь на token.Type начинаю потихоньку добавлять строчки до отладочной "вот сейчас неожиданно было".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обрабатываете при помощи Json.Net:

```
var src1 = @"{
  ""Id"": {  ""oid"":""100""},
  ""Date"": ""2018-11-15"",
  ""ImageUrl"": ""https://yyy.com""
}";

var event1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event>(src1);
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всю логику показал только чтобы был пример для разминки. Естественно, нужны разнообразные проверки на то, что у вас внутри токена будет. Может быть там будет не первым элементом $oid, а может он будет вторым -- но для начала погружения в тему сойдёт.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Custom Deserialization using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40439290/5752652)
- [Пример на нестандартный парсинг даты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/830323/213987)

Пример с датами разбирать будет сложнее (там вложенность дерева больше).

А более аккуратный способ парсинга посмотрите как раз [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40439290/5752652):

```
JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
if (obj["Code"] != null)
    return obj["Code"].ToString();
else
    return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Да первый раз так и есть. Завтра попробую и отмечу если получится.