# Как правильно преобразовать JSON в модель?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Делаю запрос к API в формате JSON, необходимо преобразовать его в модель C#.

JSON:

```
{
  "type":"INDIVIDUAL",
  "country": "US",
  "profileFields":[
    {
      "fieldId": "individualLegalName",
      "value": "Johnny Quest"
    },
    {
      "fieldId": "individualEmail",
      "value": "JohnnyQuest22@yolo.com"
    },
    {
      "fieldId": "individualResidenceAddress",
      "value": {
        "street1": "1 Market St",
        "street2": "Suite 402",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "postalCode": "94105",
        "country": "US"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Сейчас отправляю как:

```
var body = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "type", "INDIVIDUAL" },
    { "country", "US" },
    { "profileFields", "test@sendwyre.com" }
};
```

Хочу сделать через форму, думаю для этого подойдет создание модели.

Comment: Обычно не делают плоский словарь ключ-значение, обычно делают [классы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829931/213987) (удобно, автоматизировано -- есть готовые онлайн-инструменты для генерации классов и даже в студию встроен), для плоского справочника смотрите в сторону [кастомной десериализации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/906894/213987) (может быть очень утомительно и сложно).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)

Comment: @Barlukov Я ответил на ваш вопрос, ответ вам нравиться или внесете какие-то уточнения?

Answer (score 3):

У вас есть два пути.

## **Метод 1. XSD tool**

---

Предположим, что ваш XML-файл тут: `C:\path\to\xml\file.xml`

1. Откройте **Командную Строку Разработчика**
   Она находится `Кнопка Пуск> Программы> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 > Visual Studio Tools` или если у вас Windows 8/10 просто начните печатать **Командная Строка** в меню Пуск
2. Переместитесь в каталог вашего XML-файла, введя `cd /D "C:\path\to\xml"`
3. Создайте XSD файл из вашего xml файла введя`xsd file.xml`
4. Создайте C# классы введя `xsd /c file.xsd`

И это всё!
Вы сгенерировали C# классы из xml файла в `C:\path\to\xml\file.cs`

## **Метод 2 - Специальная  вставка**

---

Нужна Visual Studio 2012+

1. Скопируйте содержимое XML-файла в буфер обмена
2. Добавьте в ваш солюшн новый пустой файл класса (`Shift`+`Alt`+`C`)
3. Откройте добавленный файл и в меню выберите `Edit > Paste special > Paste JSON As Classes`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И это всё!

## **Использование**

---

Использовать очень просто с этим вспомогательным классом::

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; // Add reference: System.Web.Extensions
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Helpers
{
    internal static class ParseHelpers
    {
        private static JavaScriptSerializer json;
        private static JavaScriptSerializer JSON { get { return json ?? (json = new JavaScriptSerializer()); } }

        public static Stream ToStream(this string @this)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(@this);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }


        public static T ParseXML<T>(this string @this) where T : class
        {
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(@this.Trim().ToStream(), new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document });
            return new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader) as T;
        }

        public static T ParseJSON<T>(this string @this) where T : class
        {
            return JSON.Deserialize<T>(@this.Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Все что вам нужно сделать это:

```
 public class JSONRoot
    {
        public catalog catalog { get; set; }
    }
    // ...

    string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\file.xml");
    var catalog1 = xml.ParseXML<catalog>();

    string json = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\file.json");
    var catalog2 = json.ParseJSON<JSONRoot>();
```

**Причем так вы можете десереализовывать не только JSON но и XML это достаточно универсальное решение** ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

я перевел ответ с [английского so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document/19613934#19613934)

Comment: Ответ про какие-то древние версии студии. В 2017 жмём Edit -> Paste special -> Paste JSON as classes. Также, нужно помнить, что студийный инструмент кривой в части того, что не умеет создавать корректные описания для json содержащих ассоциативные массивы

Comment: @AK я перевел ответ с английского so мне первый метод помог, опечатку исправил.