# Десериализация JSON с массивами в C#

Tags: c#, json

JSON файл содержит поле и три массива. Первые 2 массива описывают данные, последний массив содержит массивы с данными, каждый массив это один тип данных описанный в предыдущем массиве. Пример:

```
{
            "head": "111",
            "original": [
                "1",
                "4",
                "5",
            ],
            "fields": [
                "Rid",
                "Guid",
                "Options",
            ],
            "values": [
                [
                    6,
                    0,
                    1,
                [
                    "{0047B3AB-08B9-1D40-052C-D85868CC4F33}",
                    "{15DB501E-DBBD-EB79-0E64-225FDBEA848E}",
                    "{137555FA-DDDF-7AC3-9E61-AD1E0A5402EA}",
                ],
                [
                    0,
                    0,
                    11,
                ],
            ]
        }
```

Если запарсить мой пример используя объект:

```
public class Shtable
{
    public string head { get; set; }
    public string[] original { get; set; }
    public string[] fields { get; set; }
    public object[][] values { get; set; }
}
```

То можно разобрать массивы следующий кодом:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Shtable.Count(); x++)
{
     Value value= new Value 
     {
          Rid = (long)values[0][x], // 6
          Guid = (string)values[1][x], // "{0047B3AB-08B9-1D40-052C-D85868CC4F33}"
          Options = (long)values[2][x] // 0
     }
}
```

Проблема в том что количество полей не 3, а 69. Хочется избежать использования циклов.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)

Comment: В чем собственно проблема? Если вы не знаете как дессериализовать, то смотрите ссылку в комментарии выше, если у вас проблема составить правильно класс, то покажите ваши попытки.

Comment: Скопировать JSON, далее в Visual Studio Правка -> Специальная вставка -> Вставить JSON как классы. Затем использовать эти классы для десериализации...

Comment: @AK Уже смотрел по ссылке, не мой вариант описан.

Comment: Студия автоматически сформировала классы, спасибо @XelaNimed
    public class Shtable  
    {  
        public string head { get; set; }  
        public string[] original { get; set; }  
        public string[] fields { get; set; }  
        public object[][] values { get; set; }  
    }  
Но меня не устраивает как разбиты значения, это все тот же массив. Можно использовать for и собрать собственный класс, но может быть есть более правильное решение? Может каждый массив values десериализовать отдельно?

Comment: готовые классы в студии или онлайн-инструментов (всё это было по ссылке на дубликат)  - это самое дешёвое решение по количеству затраченного времени разработчика. если вам хочется собственный класс со структурой, отличной от пришедшей в запросе - вам нужно либо писать преобразование из автоклассов в нужные вам (и это дольше, чем готовые классы), либо парсить вручную типа как тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/954681/213987 (это ещё дольше по времени). Я бы сильно задумался над тем, чтобы заставить разрабов json'а поменять формат или самому решить, стоит ли свои кастомные классы делать.

Answer (score 0):

Разбирается такой JSON весьма не сложно. Первый 2 массива содержат наименование полей данных, создаем из одного из них справочник индексов(в примере я взял original):

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int x = 0; x < original.Length; x++) dict.Add(original[x], x);
```

И уже потом заходим в цикл и выбираем поля по их идентификаторам из массива original

```
for (int x = 0; x < Shtable.Count(); x++)
{
     Value value= new Value 
     {
          Rid = (long)values[dict["1"]][x], // 6
          Guid = (string)values[dict["4"]][x], // "{0047B3AB-08B9-1D40-052C-D85868CC4F33}"
          Options = (long)values[dict["5"]][x] // 0
     }
}
```