# Зачем задавать переменной тип массив?

Tags: php

Иногда встрачаю такие записи:

```
$arr = array(); // зачем писать эту строку?
$arr = [1,2,3];
print_r($arr);
```

Ещё где-то краем уха слышал, что от этой первой строчки, как-то снижается нагрузка на проц. Поправьте, если я слышал звон.

Comment: `array()` или `[]`(это сокращение `array()`), в версиях ниже 5.4 это будет синтаксической ошибкой. Еще можете воспользоваться `SplFixedArray` иногда бывает быстрее обычного нативного `array()`. Вообще на самомо деле, массивы очень быстрые, если у вас еще есть опкешеры и прочие контроллеры... Может заметно ускорить процесс.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем примере первая строчка - лишняя и она не дает никакого снижения нагрузки на проц. Наверное, вы видели немного другой вариант использования инициализации массивов:

```
$arr = [];
$arr[1] = 'one';
print_r($arr);
```

В таком случае инициализировать массив необходимо ($arr = [] или $arr = array()), так как если переменная $arr была использована где-то еще ранее в коде  ($arr['product_id'] = 321), то в ней могут остаться данные, что может стать сюрпризом при выборке этих данных.

Comment: как связаны части предложения "в таком случае необходимо" и "так как если"? Перечитал три раза - бессмыслица какая-то.

Comment: @n.osennij когда вы вносите весь массив за раз, например так: $arr = [1,2,3], то все данные, которые были в переменной $arr затираются и вместо них записывается массив [1,2,3]. Но если вы вносите данные в массив без его инициализации, например где-то ранее внесли $arr['product_id'] = 321 а потом $arr[1] = 'one' то ваш массив будет содержать 2 ключа: `product_id` и `1`, что может стать большим неприятным сюрпризом.

Comment: Это понятно. Но написано совсем не ясно, если честно. Да и пример кода не содержим в себе того, что вы описываете ниже. И никак не объясняется  снижение нагрузки на проц

Comment: @n.osennij А тут и нет никакого снижения нагрузки на проц, поэтому это и не описано =)

Comment: Но написано так, словно вариант задавшего вопрос не даёт снижения на проц, а код ответившего, приведённые ниже - даёт.

Comment: @n.osennij первую строку прочтите, про снижение нагрузки там есть, дальше разжевано для чего это может быть использовано =)

Comment: Я про структуру и расстановку акцентов говорю. Например "Объявление переменной не увеличивает нагрузку на процессор. Что касается вашего примера, то...". Чувствуете разницу?

Comment: @n.osennij Если это мне адресовано - то тут нет моего примера =) А что хотел донести автор ответа - я прекрасно понял и лишь говорю об этом =)
Был конкретный вопрос, **есть ли тут снижение нагрузки** и очень конкретный ответ: **это не дает снижения нагрузки**... Дальше было обьяснение где и для чего такую конструкцию использовать( и что в примере вопроса эта конструкция не несет никакого смысла), что автор ответа успешно донес, по крайней мере до меня =)

Comment: @n.osennij и ваш и мой вариант - это одно и то же, написанное разными словами.

Comment: Видно я чуточку больше гуманитарий... Это не одно и то же. Вы пишете, что "В вашем примере нет снижения нагрузки". А дальше приводите сразу же свои примеры. Нет однозначности и закрытости вопроса. Вы говорите только о том, что именно код пользователя не даёт снижения нагрузки. Не больше. Ни меньше. И остаётся открытий вопрос - если не код пользователя даёт снижение, то какой код? Ладно, не важно.

Comment: @n.osennij Пожалуйста, перечитайте внимательно мой ответ. Я пищу: "В вашем примере первая строчка - лишняя и она не дает никакого снижения нагрузки на проц" - этот ответ однозначен и не нужно искать в нем скрытый смысл.

Comment: Не важно. Я уже понял, что затронул слишком тонкие материи. Проехали.

Answer (score 2):

> зачем писать эту строку?

В конкретно вашем примере - это делать не нужно. Инициализация "пустой" переменной с определением какого-то типа (string, array, integer) нужно в тех случаях, когда ниже по коду эта переменная будет принимать участие в каких-либо операциях. Например, если вы будете добавлять очередное значение в массив, то этот массив, пусть и пустой, уже должен существовать. Если будем говорить о строках, то тут может идти речь о конкатенации и чтобы "склеить" значения в переменной, в ней уже должна быть хоть какая-то строка. То же самое и числовыми типами и, например, возможных математических операциях.

```
$arr = [];
// где-то ниже
$arr[] = 'new value';

$str = '';
// где-то ниже
$str .= 'new value';

$int = 0;
// где-то ниже
$int++;
```

Что касается `$arr = []` и `$arr = array()`, то принципиальной разницы нет. Первый вариант введен, как короткий синтаксис в PHP5.4

Answer (score -3):

Для читабельности. В PHP нет способа объявить массив, поэтому иногда так и пишут.
Но ваш пример очень прост. Обычно присвоение непустого массива происходит где-то чуть ниже в коде.

Comment: $arr = [] - что это, как не объявление массива?

Comment: "В PHP нет способа объявить массив". А `$array = []` тогда что?

Comment: Чуваки, учите матчасть. 
Это не только объявление, но ещё и операция присвоения значения(пустого массива).

Comment: "нет способа объявить массив", "это не только объявление". Не говорите чушь.

Comment: "Не говорите чушь." - Хорошо. Продолжайте жить в мире, в котором единственный ЯП это PHP :)

Comment: Присвоить переменной пустой массив, через `[]` или `array()` или указать `SplFixedArray` - фиксированный массив. Уже будет говорить о том, что в переменной находится тип массива.

Comment: О, я смотрю вы не только в [парсинге json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/921414/213987) спец, но ещё и в PHP. Вам бы может поменьше апломба...

Comment: @And: А я и не отрицаю этого. Я говорю про то, что объявление и опеределение это разные вещи.
@A K: "Вам бы может поменьше апломба..." - Так же как и некоторым другим пользователям so )

Comment: Тем не менее, в коде в вопросе тоже присваивание, а не объявление.